# Watson Assistant - Option response type in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, integration, messenger, watson-assistant

I've got a 352 Intents and 1051 Dialog Nodes WA chatbot, with lots of "Option response type". It's kind of a Menu-base chatbot.

I want to integrate it with Facebook Messenger. I know WA has his own integration, I already did it, but I've got the problem with the "Option response type":

- Labels' char lenght are, usually, bigger then Messenger limits;
- Buttons appear only in the bottom of a response, in an horizontal scrool list.

I wonder if it's possible to overcome these 2 limitations, and show an "Option response type" in Facebook Messenger like a List box, instead of the default horizontal scrool...

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM out of the box Facebook integration is limited by Facebook's messenger API. The default buttons are FB quick replies (a type of default button). FB does have an larger set of interaction types via what they call templates. However you would need to develop your own integration layer to make use of a larger set of FB elements. You will still find however that FB is far more limited with some items like button labels etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you give me an example of an "integration layer", so I could "customize" messenger buttons? thanks

Comment: By integration layer, I mean writing your own layer in nodejs for example, that links FB to Watson. BotKit is one example many people use to create their own integration layer.  Normally I look at the API's used by the target platform and write my own.